# Problems with SQL filter in Windows Azure Topics

Tags: azure

I'm creating an SQL filter for a cloud service which uses topics/ subscriptions. I declared a property for my brokered message which looks something like this

```
BrokeredMessage message = new BrokeredMessage("Response Message#"+ (++counter) +" Body");

// Set additional custom app-specific property
message.Properties["MsgGUID"] = RequestMessageID; //assign msgGUID read from the Azure Queue

// Send message to the topic
Client.Send(message);
```

What is want to achieve is when i send a message to my worker role, the message will contain a randomly generated string. The worker role will treat that string as my ID and create a brokered message, whose "MsgGUID" property will  hold the ID. My SQL filter looks like the following :

```
SqlFilter CompareGUIDFilter = new SqlFilter("MsgGUID = '" + messageID + "'");//Filter based on the Requested GUID i.e. msgGUID

if (!nameSpaceManager.SubscriptionExists("TestTopic", "RequestMessageGUIDSubscriber"))
            {
                /*Subscriber with Filter as Receive only those Messages from the Topic that are 
                requested by the controller from another RequestQueue(Azure Queue) with GUID as messageID*/
                nameSpaceManager.CreateSubscription("TestTopic", "RequestMessageGUIDSubscriber", CompareGUIDFilter);

            }
```

And my randomly generated string looks like the following:

```
public string GetRandomString(int length)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            string result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                result += allowedchars.Substring(r.Next(0,allowedchars.Length),1);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Now the problem is when i set messageId to something static, like "GUID", then the filter works properly, but when i generate it using the above function, it does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem in the sql filter. But the Topic persists the message in it with that id key value. And hence you are not able to access the later messages via your subscribers.